# Find all eigenvalues of $S, T$ and their corresponding algebraic multiplicities and geometric multiplicities.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given transformations $S, T$ on $V$ (dim($V$)=$n$), and $S^2=0=T^2, ST=-TS+I$, where I is the identity transformation. Find all eigenvalues of $S, T$ and their corresponding algebraic multiplicities and geometric multiplicities.

From the conditions $S^2=T^2=0$, $\forall x \in V$, it is easy to find that $$S(Sx)=0\\ Sx\in Ker(S)$$
Then $\forall y\in Ker(S)$, we have $Sy=0$, then $y=S(2Ty)$. Finally we have $Ker(S)=Im(S)=Sker(T)$, so is $T$.

Hence for eigenvalues of $S$, I can only find a $0$ by directly looking, and I guess they are the specific number like $0, 1$. For algebraic and geometric multiplicities, I cannot get them in a general way, it seems hard to get the characteristic polynomial.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the two given conditions are correct? They seem to be contradicting each other.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this mistake. Yes, the coefficient of $ST$ and $TS$ must be equal, it does have a mistake.

Comment: What is the underlying field? If it's $\mathbb R$, the modified condition $2ST=2TS+I$ is impossible, if you take traces on both sides.

Comment: If $S^n = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$, then all eigenvalues of $S$ are zero. This is clear to see from the fact that the minimal polynomial divides $x^n$, and the fact that the roots of the minimal polynomial contain all the eigenvalues.

Comment: My mistake, forgot to type the negative sign... Thank you @user1551

Comment: You keep changing the conditions... what is the source of this question?

Comment: They are nilpotent so they only have eigenvalue 0, then it seems $n$ must be even, so the multiplicity is $\frac{n}{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the given conditions, we see that $ST$ and $TS$ are idempotent. Since $ST$ and $TS$ also share the same spectrum, they are projections of the same rank $r$.

Let $X=STV$ and $Y=TSV$. Then $\dim X=\dim Y=r$. As $STY=0$, we see that $X\cap Y=0$. Since $ST+TS=I$, we infer that $V=X\oplus Y$ and $n=2r$.

The given conditions also imply that $S=STS$. Therefore $SV=STSV\subseteq STV\subseteq SV$. Hence $SV=STV$ and $\operatorname{rank}(S)=\operatorname{rank}(ST)=r$.

Since $S$ is nilpotent, all its eigenvalues are zero. The geometric multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is the thus nullity of $S$, which, by the rank-nullity theorem, is equal to $n-r=r$. The same conclusion can be drawn for $T$ by a similar argument.

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix squares to zero, its only eigenvalue is zero. To see it, if $x\in V,x\not=0$ is an eigenvector for $x$ then
$$
Ax=\lambda x\Rightarrow 0=A^2x=\lambda^2x\Rightarrow \lambda^2=0\Rightarrow \lambda=0.
$$
Hence $S,T$ have only zero eigenvalues.

Let us now also assume that $ST+TS=I$. Then WLOG(*) we can assume $S$ is in Jordan canonical form, namely
$$
S=J_1\oplus\cdots\oplus J_k
$$
where $J_i$ are Jordan blocks of size $d_i$. Since $J_i^2=0$ we necessarily have either $d_i=1$ or $d_i=2$.
We claim now that necessarily $d_i=2$; otherwise if there is a vanishing Jordan block of size zero, say at position $(i,i)$ in the matrix $S$, then the entry $(i,i)$ of the identity $ST+TS=I$ would give $0=1$, a contradiction.

Thus all Jordan blocks of $S$ are $2\times 2$, namely $n=2k$ is even and $S$ is (conjugate to)
$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\oplus\cdots\oplus\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{k\text { times}}.
$$
The reasoning for $T$ is completely parallel.

(*) If $S=GJG^{-1}$, $G\in{\rm GL}(V)$ and $J=J_1\oplus\dots J_k$ in Jordan canonical form, then $T'=G^{-1}TG$ satisfies $JT'+T'J=I$, so we just consider $T'$ in place of $T$.

Comment: Thank you, it does have a mistake. I have modified this question.

Comment: OK I have edited!